# Finding the ODE form of impulse response function $h(t)=e^{-at}H(t)t^n$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, linear-control

Consider a linear system that has a known impulse response function $h(t)=e^{-at}H(t)(at)^n$ where $a$ and $n$ are known coefficients and $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function. If there is an external force applied to the system, $x(t)$, the output of the system can be written as a convolution

$$
y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t - \tau) x(\tau)\ d\tau.
$$

**My question** is for non-integer $n > 0$, how can we write the system in the first order ODE format? That is,

$$
\frac{d \mathbf{s}}{dt} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{s}, x)
$$
for some states $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and some function $\mathbf{f}(\cdot)$, and the output is determined by
$$
y = g(\mathbf{s})
$$
with some function $g(\cdot)$.

**What I have done**

For integer $n$, I know how to solve it. First, take the simplest example where $n = 0$. The output $y$ can be written as

$$
y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(t-\tau)}H(t - \tau) x(\tau) d\tau
$$
where the derivative is
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[-a H(t - \tau) + \delta(t-\tau)\right] e^{-a(t-\tau)} x(\tau) d\tau
$$
with $\delta(\cdot)$ as the Dirac delta function, and can be simplified into
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}(t) =-a y(t) + x(t)
$$

So in the case of $n = 0$, we can write $ds/dt = f(s, x) = -a s + x$ with the output $y = g(s) = s$.
The similar procedure can be repeated for $n = 1$, but in this case we need to differentiate $y$ twice, and get
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}(t) =-2 a \frac{dy}{dt}(t) - a^2 y(t) + 2 a x(t).
$$
With the equation above, we can write the first order ODE form by choosing the states $\mathbf{s} = (dy/dt, y)$.

Similar procedures can be done for integer $n \geq 0$. However, it is unclear to me how to get such equation with non-integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linear time invariant systems one can only achieve systems with impulse responses which have integer values for $n$, by having $n+1$ repeated poles at $-a$. Namely, by taking the [Laplace transform of $h(t)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=laplace+transform+exp%28-a*t%29*%28a*t%29%5En) yields

$$
\mathcal{L}\{h(t)\}(s) = \frac{n!\,a^n}{(s+a)^{n+1}}.
$$

---

However, it can be quite easy to solve this problem by adding time dependency to $g(s)$. If you do not want to add time as input parameter one can also achieve the same behavior using an extra state with a time derivative of always one, for example using $s\in\mathbb{R}^2$

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 \\ s_2
\end{bmatrix}&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-a\,s_1+x \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}, \\
y &= s_1\,(a\,s_2)^n,
\end{align}

since $s_2$ would be equal to $t$ (assuming that the impulse response starts at $t=0$ and $s_2(0)=0$). But this only produces the desired $h(t)$ if the impulse is applied at $t=0$.

One can tweak the proposed model a little, such that the impulse response does match when applied at different times using

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 \\ s_2 \\ s_3
\end{bmatrix}&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-a\,s_1+x \\ s_3 \\
x
\end{bmatrix}, \\
y &= s_1\,(a\,s_2)^n,
\end{align}

with $s_2(0)=0$ and $s_3(0)=0$. Namely, applying an [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions) at time $t_i$ yields that at an infinitesimal time step after $t=t_i$ $s_3(t)=1$ and thus the rest of the dynamics is equivalent to the previous model but starting at $t=t_i$ instead of $t=0$.
This probably also doesn't give the intended behavior, for example applying a different magnitude impulse yields that $s_2$ would grow at a different rate as time.

---

Instead, one can also construct a linear time invariant system that approximates the impulse response. Such an approximation can for example be obtained by taking a [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) of the factional part of the given Laplace transform of $h(t)$ given above and use is as the transfer function for the system.

For example taking a (3,3) order Padé approximant using $n = 1/2$ and $a=1$ yields

$$
\frac{1}{(s+1)^{1/2}} \approx \frac{s^3 + 24\,s^2 + 80\,s + 64}{7\,s^3 + 56\,s^2 + 112\,s + 64},
$$

$$
\frac{1/2!}{(s+1)^{3/2}} \approx
\frac{1/2!}{(s+1)}\frac{s^3 + 24\,s^2 + 80\,s + 64}{7\,s^3 + 56\,s^2 + 112\,s + 64}.
$$

Plotting the impulse response of this transfer function, denoted with $\tilde{h}(t)$, and comparing it to $h(t)$ yields

[image]

Comment: $y$ in your expression is not equal to the $y$ wanted in the question. With the ODE system above, $s_1 = \int e^{-a(t-\tau)} H(t-\tau) x(\tau) d\tau$ and $s_2 = t$. Therefore, $y=\int e^{-a(t-\tau)}H(t-\tau) (a t)^n x(\tau) d\tau$ which does not quite give the impulse response in question. (Note that we want $(a (t - \tau))^n$ in the question instead of $(a t)^n$).

Comment: @Firman impulse responses only satisfy this behavior for linear time invariant (LTI) systems. Since you are considering nonlinear functions for $f(s,x)$ and $g(s)$ then it will not hold. One can approximate it, but it will only be equal in the limit as the order of the system (so the size of the state vector $s$) goes to infinity.

Comment: @Firman I have updated my answer with an expansion on my initial solution and and added a section of using an approximation.

Comment: How to convert from those Pade approximation back to the states $d\mathbf{s}/dt = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{s}, x)$?

Comment: @Firman $f(s,x)$ and $g(s)$ will be linear time invariant state space models. There are multiple ways of converting from a transfer function to such state space model, for [example see this](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html).

Comment: @Firman it can be noted that the state space model is not unique, since one can apply an infinite number of similarity transformations, which change the used state representation. In many programming languages there are also functions available which do this conversion for you, most of which should also give numerically stable state space model representation. (For example the controllable canonical form I believe is often not a good choice).

Answer (score 0):

The following works: let $m=2$,  $g(s_1,s_2)=s_1$ and $$f_1(\mathbf{s},x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(a(s_2-\tau))^{n} e^{-a(s_2-\tau)} H(s_2-\tau) x(\tau) d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{s_2}(a(s_2-\tau))^{n} e^{-a(s_2-\tau)} x(\tau) d\tau$$ and $f_2(\mathbf{s},x)=1$, but that is probably not what you want. The problem is that if $n$ is not an integer, and you want an equation that only depends on the current state, you would need an infinite state space. Another possibility could be a fractional differential equation. You can read more about the latter for example on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus .

For the infinite state space, if $x$ is causal then the integral reduces to $$y(t)=\int_0^{t}e^{-a(t-\tau)} (a(t-\tau))^n x(\tau)d\tau.$$ Then $|\frac{\tau}{t}|\leq 1$ and you can use the binomial series to expand $$(t-\tau)^n=t^n\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}\left(-\frac{\tau}{t}\right)^k=\tau^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}(-1)^k \left(\frac{\tau}{t}\right)^{k-n}.$$
You can use this construct the states.